# Rename dash in JasperServer List Filter control to something meaningful

Tags: filter, jasper-reports, jasperserver

The list filter control in JasperServer shows "---" as the default options.

What's the procedure to rename it to something meaningful, such as "ALL"?

It doesn't seem to be in jasperserver_message.properties. Is there any other location, where we need to make the change? Or, does it require rewriting of filter control itself?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested... but I searched like this: `grep -rn "\-\-\-" ./webapps/jrs-pro-5.0.1/WEB-INF/bundles`

/usr/local/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/jrs-pro-5.0.2/WEB-INF/bundles/querybuilder_messages.properties

Line 65: page.filters.filter.empty.string=---

"ALL" would be more obviously meaningful... but in many cases the meaning would be wrong. But if your reports are defined so that not selecting a value results in all results being returned, then it could be a good customization in your deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, mdahlman. It seems querybuilder_message.properties is available only in the pro version. The file doesn't exist in Community edition. Also, the grep command doesn't return anything relevant in the bundles folder. :(

Comment: @Gopal If that file is from the pro build, then it's not the file that controls the string you're interested in. So my untested guess appears to have been wrong. That string is controlled identically in the pro and community versions.